# My Game crash in Samsung gives error: signal 11 (SIGSEGV), code 1 (SEGV_MAPERR), fault addr 0x4

Tags: android, cocos2d-x

My game facing this crash sometime in particular Samsung Device, and i dint know what to do for this type of problem. I have already import `app compatibility v7` in my project.

```
Build fingerprint: 'samsung/grandppltedtvvj/grandppltedtv:6.0.1/MMB29T/G532MTVJU1AQB1:user/release-keys'
Revision: '5'
ABI: 'arm'
pid: 22325, tid: 22341, name: GLThread 42320  >>> com.abc.candy <<<
signal 11 (SIGSEGV), code 1 (SEGV_MAPERR), fault addr 0x4
    r0 00000000  r1 00000000  r2 00000000  r3 00000000
    r4 00000001  r5 00000001  r6 00000001  r7 00000001
    r8 00000001  r9 b31a1f00  sl 00000000  fp b2f402bc
    ip b2f3fec4  sp b2f402a8  lr 9edd50d4  pc 9ee82900  cpsr 200f0010

backtrace:
    #00 pc 0062e900  /data/app/com.abc.candy-1/lib/arm/libcocos2dcpp.so (_ZN7cocos2d3Ref6retainEv+20)
    #01 pc 005810d0  /data/app/com.abc.candy2-1/lib/arm/libcocos2dcpp.so (_ZN7cocos2d6Sprite14setSpriteFrameEPNS_11SpriteFrameE+92)
    #02 pc 00580fc4  /data/app/com.abc.candy-1/lib/arm/libcocos2dcpp.so (_ZN7cocos2d6Sprite14setSpriteFrameERKSs+616)
    #03 pc 0041c23c  /data/app/com.abc.candy-1/lib/arm/libcocos2dcpp.so (_ZN9GameScene15generateSpecialEP5CandySsii+844)
    #04 pc 00425e18  /data/app/com.abc.candy-1/lib/arm/libcocos2dcpp.so
    #05 pc 00432cfc  /data/app/com.abc.candy-1/lib/arm/libcocos2dcpp.so
    #06 pc 004dba4c  /data/app/com.abc.candy-1/lib/arm/libcocos2dcpp.so (_ZNKSt8functionIFvvEEclEv+60)
    #07 pc 004dabec  /data/app/com.abc.candy-1/lib/arm/libcocos2dcpp.so (_ZN7cocos2d8CallFunc7executeEv+204)
    #08 pc 004dab14  /data/app/com.abc.candy-1/lib/arm/libcocos2dcpp.so (_ZN7cocos2d8CallFunc6updateEf+40)
    #09 pc 004df2bc  /data/app/com.abc.candy-1/lib/arm/libcocos2dcpp.so (_ZN7cocos2d8Sequence6updateEf+1140)
    #10 pc 004de3a8  /data/app/com.abc.candy-1/lib/arm/libcocos2dcpp.so (_ZN7cocos2d14ActionInterval4stepEf+584)
    #11 pc 0073c4f4  /data/app/com.abc.candy-1/lib/arm/libcocos2dcpp.so (_ZN7cocos2d13ActionManager6updateEf+244)
    #12 pc 00603000  /data/app/com.abc.candy-1/lib/arm/libcocos2dcpp.so (_ZZN7cocos2d9Scheduler14scheduleUpdateINS_13ActionManagerEEEvPT_ibENKUlfE_clEf+36)
    #13 pc 00604b9c  /data/app/com.abc.candy-1/lib/arm/libcocos2dcpp.so (_ZNSt17_Function_handlerIFvfEZN7cocos2d9Scheduler14scheduleUpdateINS1_13ActionManagerEEEvPT_ibEUlfE_E9_M_invokeERKSt9_Any_dataf+60)
    #14 pc 004ea360  /data/app/com.abc.candy-1/lib/arm/libcocos2dcpp.so (_ZNKSt8functionIFvfEEclEf+88)
    #15 pc 0063aeac  /data/app/com.abc.candy-1/lib/arm/libcocos2dcpp.so (_ZN7cocos2d9Scheduler6updateEf+172)
    #16 pc 005fe90c  /data/app/com.abc.candy-1/lib/arm/libcocos2dcpp.so (_ZN7cocos2d8Director9drawSceneEv+160)
    #17 pc 00602d74  /data/app/com.abc.candy-1/lib/arm/libcocos2dcpp.so (_ZN7cocos2d19DisplayLinkDirector8mainLoopEv+136)
    #18 pc 004638a0  /data/app/com.abc.candy-1/lib/arm/libcocos2dcpp.so (Java_org_cocos2dx_lib_Cocos2dxRenderer_nativeRender+40)
    #19 pc 006da6a5  /data/app/com.abc.candy-1/oat/arm/base.odex (offset 0x512000)

Build fingerprint: 'samsung/j23gdd/j23g:5.1.1/LMY48B/J200HXXU0APK1:user/release-keys'
Revision: '2'
ABI: 'arm'
pid: 22292, tid: 22310, name: GLThread 3374  >>> com.abc.candy <<<
signal 11 (SIGSEGV), code 1 (SEGV_MAPERR), fault addr 0x20
    r0 9f21dc00  r1 00000078  r2 00000078  r3 00000000
    r4 a3396b5c  r5 a2dcbd5c  r6 9f21dc00  r7 9f280184
    r8 010f03ce  r9 b4428400  sl 00000000  fp a264e854
    ip 9f21dc00  sp a264e800  lr a2c68d48  pc a2c68b4c  cpsr 800f0010
```

All this crash comes in Samsung device not in other device.

Answer (score 0):

You can check the exact line number where crash occurs by using following :-
When you get errors like this on the LogCat, they are saved on $PROJECT_PATH/obj/local/armeabi where $PROJECT_PATH is the path to your cocos2d-x android project. To symbolicate the messages to something understandable, you can use the ndk-stack tool.

Open up the Terminal (or Cygwin, not sure though) and type in

cd $ANDROID_NDK
adb logcat | ./ndk-stack -sym $PROJECT_PATH/obj/local/armeabi
where:

$ANDROID_NDK is the path to your android NDK

$PROJECT_PATH is the path to your cocos2d-x android project